# PowerShell Script output not aligning

Tags: powershell, console, buffer

When typed in directly into PowerShell this works just fine. But when put in a script form the output of Get-Volume appears after the second Read-Host. Not sure why this is happening. Buffer issue?

```
Read-Host "I'm going to print out Get-Volume"

Get-Volume

Read-Host "Wait where did it go? Funny it will actually write out below this line."
```

Comment: I believe when you are running the code from a script it is acting a bit more like a function where output is returned at the end of the function call.  if you change the line to `Get-Volume | Out-Host` it will output the results immediately

Comment: Wow yeah that's exactly right. So weird, thanks for the input!